# Windows.Storage.Search.dll high CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

I am observing this behavior from several days, when I use my PC after sometime of inactivity, `Runtime Broker` start using high CPU usage. When I check it using process explorer, there are two threads that caused high CPU usage.

> Windows.Storage.Search.dll!GetGatherAdmin+0xd2e0
>   windows.storage.dll!SHGetNameFromIDList+0x1c0

But I don't understand what these are and how to stop this issue? Any advice?

Comment: I need a xperf trace to see more details. install the Windows 10 WPT (part of the Windows 10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), and run the commands shown in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD share the compressed ETL file

Comment: have you captured a trace of the high CPU usage?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry I didn't got time to test it. I want to try it myself. Although I have install the SDK. I will update you once it is done

Comment: @magicandre1981 Hi, I failed to understand this. I don't want to upload the results publicly. Can you mail me with your E-Mail ID so I can I send you the results privately. My E-Mail is listed on my profile

Comment: ok, I wrote you an email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Runtime Broker tries to read a thumbnail `windows.storage.dll!CFSFolder::_GetThumbnailCacheId` and this casues a high CPU usage. But I can't see which process/app triggers this call. Close all of the Store Apps (Microsoft.Windows.Photos is a good candidate) and see what happens.

Comment: I think you are right. I opened the Photo app and noticed sudden increase in CPU usage. I also noticed it was scanning a very big partition with lot of images. I have removed the directory, will see if it works

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Comment: I haven't faced this issue again so far. I guess it worked. Thanks